# keystroke to move to end of whitespace

Tags: key-bindings

I often want to select the whitespace on the line I'm editing to remove it. For instance I have a couple of lines that I want to bring onto one. Example:

Starting with:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(
                new TestDbContextBindings());
```

Then:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(                new TestDbContextBindings());
```

Desired result:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestDbContextBindings());
```

In order to get to the "desired result" what key combo is most efficient please?

Comment: `g_` moves to beginning of whitespace (sort of). But yea, Rich's `Jx` is definitely the easiest here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific example, starting with the cursor anywhere on the first line, I would type <kbd>J</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>. (See [`:help J`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#J).)

More generally, for whitespace that already exists on a single line, I would use something like <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to remove it, <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to visually select it, or <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>[char]</kbd> to just move the cursor to the end of the whitespace that is followed by a `[char]` character. There's no shortage of other solutions, but these are pretty simple and easy to use.

Comment: The `J` `x` answer is awesome!! Thank you. This will save me loads of time every day.